# Shared email on 2 Facebook accounts is stopping access to both accounts

Tags: facebook

My husband wanted me to set up a Facebook account for him and I accidentally used our shared email address, which is set against my own account.  Since then, neither of us has been able to log in, so I can't alter any settings.  Can anyone advise how to resolve this please?

Comment: Please update with more information, for example what notices Facebook sent.

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't have happened, since Facebook checks if the email is already used or not.

> If you are not the account owner and are attempting to sign up for an account, then please be aware that you can only sign up for one Facebook account per email address.

From [here](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=175050382551472).

However, try using [this](http://www.facebook.com/help/reg.php?show_form=dup_email) form to regain access to your account.

Or try one of the following procedures:

> **I can’t remember which email address I use to log in to Facebook.**
>
> 1. If you registered a username, try [logging in](http://www.facebook.com/login.php) using your username and password. A username is your personalized Facebook URL (web address) and appears in the location bar of your browser after "http://www.facebook.com/" when you view your profile. After logging in, visit the [Account Settings](http://www.facebook.com/settings) page to locate the email address you use to log in.
> 2. Try logging in using your mobile number and password. If you have confirmed a mobile number onto your account, you can log in with your mobile number and password. Be sure to add the country code and remove leading zeroes and symbols when you enter your mobile number.
> 3. Try locating your account on the [password reset](http://www.facebook.com/reset.php) page. 
>      Tip: If you can’t find your account using one option, try using the other options to find your account.
> 4. Ask one of your Facebook friends to view your profile and send you the email address listed on your account.
>
>    - To do this, ask your friend to click on the "Info" tab on your Profile page and scroll down to "Contact Information."
>    - Once you receive this information, try [logging in](http://www.facebook.com/login.php) with that email address.
> 5. If you have followed the steps provided above and are still unable to access your account, click [here](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=forgot_login).

From [here](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=110975895658061).

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your post. I haven't had any notification from Facebook. I set up the 2nd account and it froze after I clicked 'enter' to gain access. Since then I haven't been able to get into my account at all and couldn't find anything on the Facebook log-in page that would allow me to report the problem. I'll try the additional link you sent when I get home tonight. Thanks again. Janet